# Django / Python : group results by time slots

Tags: python, django, time

I have a following data file.

```
[{'timeSlot': '10:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'},{'timeSlot': '10:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '09:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '09:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '10:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '09:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}]
```

I want to get a result in group by on time slot. What is the best method to do this?

Desired output would be something like:

```
{'09:45 AM' : [{'timeSlot': '09:45 AM', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '09:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '09:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}], 
'10:45 AM' : [{'timeSlot': '10:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '10:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}, {'timeSlot': '10:45 AM','key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is what you want:

```
from itertools import groupby

# assuming `data` is your datafile contents
keyfunc = lambda d: d['timeSlot']
dict((k, list(v)) for k, v in groupby((sorted(data, key=keyfunc)), keyfunc))
```

The call to `sorted` is necessary because otherwise `groupby` returns a new group every time the key changes. Sorting it first is analogous to calling `sort | uniq` on a bash terminal.

Also, note that `groupby` returns an iterable with keys and sub-iterators by default, hence the `dict` and `list` calls I inserted to flatten it out into the result structure you want. If you just need to iterate over the groups, it's cleaner and more efficient to just use the iterators.

Comment: Thanx for answering. Thats awesome! I can see it works by running it.  It does exactly what I want. But I also want group sort by time slot.

Comment: If you want results sorted by timeslot then a standard dictionary is not the right representation, since it's unordered. If you replace the `dict` call with `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module, that will give you what you want.